# Javascript scrolling not working safari but works on chrome OSX

Tags: javascript, css, safari

Does anyone have any ideas as to what would cause scrolling not to work on safari but to work on chrome? Both of these are on OSX.

In my console I log the delta and for some reason, for weak scrolls it always either logs 3 or -3. If I scroll a bunch of times in a row then it will eventually scroll down or up. This is parallax scrolling. Here's my code:

```
function parallaxScroll(evt) {
  console.log("what about this")
  if (isFirefox) {
    //Set delta for Firefox
    delta = evt.detail * (-120);
  } else if (isIe) {
    //Set delta for IE
    delta = -evt.deltaY;
  } else {
    //Set delta for all other browsers
    delta = evt.wheelDelta;
    console.log(delta)
  }

  if (ticking != true){
    if (delta <= -scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Down scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== (totalSlideNumber - 1)) {
        currentSlideNumber++;
        nextItem();
      }
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
    if (delta >= scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Up scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== 0) {
        currentSlideNumber--;
        previousItem();
      }
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
  }
}


.background {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 130vh;
  position: fixed;
  text-shadow: black 2px 2px 2px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
  transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
  color: #fff;
}

.background:first-child {
  background-color: rgba(156, 146, 137, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15vh, 0);
}
.background:first-child .content-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 15vh, 0);
}
.background:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(2.jpg);
}
.background:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(3.jpg);
}
.background:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 3;
}
.background:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
}
.background:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
}
.background:nth-child(n+2):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 20%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 80%, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 20%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 20%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1a000000', endColorstr='#1a000000',GradientType=1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem seemed to be not having transform: translate3d along with my webkit transforms and having overflow set to auto. Setting overflow to hidden and adding the transform: translate3d everywhere I used webkit-transform fixed the issue for me.